# ffmpeg install on windows server 2003. for use in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg, windows-server-2003

I have a rails application which uses ffmpeg for thumbnailing/duration/file format conversion of videos.
Currently my rails app runs in ubuntu - where ffmpeg works great. But due to some client constraints , need to run rails app on windows.
I tried looking out for some writeups, googling around some forums but could not get a comprehensive list of steps to run ffmpeg on windows.

Any help/alternatives/links to ge it running would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Windows builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) didn't help? Can they at least run Cygwin? In the long run that'd probably be easier.